# How to develop iOS app with different sets of graphics under Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have this app with one whole set of images, but I would like to add for example personalized set of graphics. Is there an easy way to organize and develop source code and not to get lost while switching between these sets of images?

One way I see it is to have on my hard drive two folders with graphics and before releasing replace in project current images with personalized set... is there a better way?

I'm using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.0 for this app.

Comment: Do you want to change the artwork during development or do you want to give the user the ability to switch between different sets of artwork?

Comment: at this moment I wanted to have two versions of the same app with different sets of images... I'm not sure if adding to project resources and just combining them with one of two targets would be a solution? Or is there some way better?

Comment: Do they all have the same names?

Comment: almost all of them don't

Comment: In that case swapping a folder alone won't work you'll need a way to update your code, nibs, Xcode project file, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest and most reliable in terms of maintainance is to write your own image access function or marco, that is controlled in one place globally. Then use this in all cases where you want to have the flexibility for differnt images for example like this. I just got used to this way of assigning an image with `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` because it adjusts the size nicely.

Of course you may use any other way to assign your images, like directly without use of `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth`

Anyway, this is my suggestion:

```
   NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%i",@"imageName",CONST_VERSION];
   UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:s];
   myImageView.image = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
```

and you can do

```
 #define CONST_VERSION 1 // or 2
```

Then name your images like:

```
myImage1.png
```

> `and`

```
myImage2.png
```

Comment: well, that is quite nice - but do I have to add to project all of them? I mean, isn't that making project in both cases twice as big?

Comment: the code itself does not change anything regarding the size - just the images will contribute to your app folder. The more and larger the images the more memory it will require - but I doubt you will have that many screens :-)...